# 'ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy' error when trying to run ec2 python script from ssm

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ssm

I am trying to run a python script on my ec2 instance using ssm runShellScript from Lambda. When testing with a simple script that creates a text file, it runs with no problem. I can see the text file on ec2. But when trying to run the intended python script (analyzer.py) I get the following error: 'ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy'

The script analyzer.py makes use of the sqlalchemy module. When I directly run analyzer.py from the ec2 server, the script runs just fine. Thoughts?

Comment: When you run the script directly on ec2 manually which python interpreter do you use? Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: No virtualenv... just cd into the directory and run 'python analyzer.py arg'

Comment: Can you share the script and the full error message from ssm?

Comment: `----------ERROR-------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analyzer.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy`

Won't be able to share the script though!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that when sending command to ec2 instance using ssm runShellScript, you are running as "root", which I assume does not have sqlalchemy library installed. You'll need to run as "ec2-user" (or whatever user account where you have installed sqlalchemy).

I used the following method to make it work:

1. Create a file at /home/ec2-user/run_analyzer.sh with following content:

```
cd <folder that contains analyzer.py>
python analyzer.py
```

2. Make /home/ec2-user/run_analyzer.sh executable (e.g., use "chmod +x /home/ec2-user/run_analyzer.sh")
3. Use ssm as following in your boto3 script:

```
import boto3
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
ssm_client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=["<put your instance id here>"],
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
    Parameters={'commands': [
       "sudo -i -u ec2-user /home/ec2-user/run_analyzer.sh"
    ]} )
```